# Using dynamically added widgets in PyQt/Pyside

Tags: pyqt, widget, pyside, python-3.4

I have modified the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651742/dynamically-adding-and-removing-widgets-in-pyqt) as written below. The code is basically creating pushbuttons with a counter as pushButton_0, pushButton_1..
Here, I know that when I press to `self.addButton` I am creating widgets named like `self.pushButton_0, self.pushButton_1` etc. So, my question is, how I'm supposed to use this pushbuttons? Because when I'm trying to do something like `self.pushButton_0.clicked.connect(self.x)`, it' s telling me that "there is  no attribute named 'pushButton_0'".

Thanks!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.GUI()


    def GUI(self):

        self.count = 0

        # main button
        self.addButton = QtGui.QPushButton('button to add other widgets')
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addWidget)

        # scroll area widget contents - layout
        self.scrollLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()

        # scroll area widget contents
        self.scrollWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

        # scroll area
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

        # main layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        # add all main to the main vLayout
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        # central widget
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        # set central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def addWidget(self):
        self.scrollLayout.addRow(Test(self))
        self.count = self.count + 1
        print(self.count)


class Test(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__( self, main):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.Main = main
        self.setup()


    def setup(self):

        print(self.Main.count)

        name = "pushButton_"+str(self.Main.count)
        print(name)

        self.name = QtGui.QPushButton('I am in Test widget '+str(self.Main.count))


        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.name)
        self.setLayout(layout)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWidget = Main()
myWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, in your code I do not see anything referring to what you want.

Comment: Obviously, I was trying to use the pushbutton created with a pushbutton click, please read it carefullly. But, it's solved, see below.

Answer (score 1):

After hours, I found the problem!

You have to declare the signal while creating the pushbutton!
To fix this, I rewrote the setup function as below;

```
 def setup(self):

    print(self.Main.count)

    name = "pushButton_"+str(self.Main.count)
    print(name)

    self.name = QtGui.QPushButton('I am in Test widget '+str(self.Main.count))
    self.name.clicked.connect(self.x)        # self.x is any function



    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.name)
    self.setLayout(layout)
```

So know, you will run function x whenever you push the new created pushbuttons!